# PHP/JS wav compression

Tags: php, javascript, compression

I am generating a wave file (.wav) in a PHP script on my server, which I am then sending to the client through a GET request.
Now my problem is that the download speed of the client limits the file size to be transferred in a reasonable time, so I am looking for a way to compress a file (a wav, to be precise) in PHP and decompress it again in Javascript once sent there over HTTP.

Is there a known solution to this that I am unaware of?
Will clarify question if necessary.

Comment: could look to make a zip file, not sure if that compresses it

Comment: A simple googling may reveal a garden of solutions...

Comment: Would it be acceptable to transcode the file to a compressed format, like mp3?

Comment: Now why is this not constructive? The answer I was looking for, came.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quite sure you can setup output compression in Apache for .wav files (or for any other file types actually). You don't need to handle that on PHP because Apache will compress it automatically and also no worries in Javascript since the browser will decompress it automatically (Apache sets the appropriate headers to let the browser know it needs to decompress the response).

That being said, take a look at mod_deflate for Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html